# Copy SharePoint server 2016 site from one server to another SharePoint 2016 server

Tags: server, migration, microsoft, development, sharepoint

I'm facing an issue while trying to create a development site into SharePoint 2016 server. I have site already exist in another SharePoint 2016 server and the site is running fine, now I need to replicate the functionality of that production site and create a development environment into another SharePoint 2016 server. Can someone help me out with this. How I can achieve this?